# Unarchive NSData back to NSColor in swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, nscolor

I have archived an NSColor to store it in NSUserDefaults:

```
var data = NSArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(NSColor.redColor())
storage.setObject(data, forKey: "color")
storage.synchronize()
```

But now I need to get the color back from NSData, I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use if let to unwrap your NSData and also you will need a conditional cast as follow:

edit/update:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
// archiving
let color: NSColor = .red
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "color")
```

---

```
// unarchiving 
if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "color"), 
    let loadedColor =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: loadedData) as? NSColor {
    // you can access loadedColor here
    print(loadedColor)  // "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 1 0 0 1\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into some errors trying to get Leo's answer working in Swift 5. Came up with this extension which lets UserDefaults store and retrieve colors. Try pasting this into a Playground.

```
import Cocoa

extension UserDefaults {

    func set(_ color: NSColor, forKey: String) {
        if let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: false) {
            self.set(data, forKey: forKey)
        }
    }

    func color(forKey: String) -> NSColor? {
        guard
            let storedData = self.data(forKey: forKey),
            let unarchivedData = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSColor.self, from: storedData),
            let color = unarchivedData as NSColor?
        else {
            return nil
        }

        return color
    }

}

// get defaults instance
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

// create a color
let mycolor = NSColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.8, alpha: 0.5)

// save the color
defaults.set(mycolor, forKey: "mycolor")

// read the color back. this returns an optional, may be nil
defaults.color(forKey: "mycolor")
```